# How would I create a function that takes three numbers as arguments and returns the largest of them?

Tags: javascript

I've been looking at simple JS exercises and I would appreciate it if you showed me how to approach this question or, even better, provide a solution that I can take a look at. Help much appreciated.

EDIT: I would also appreciate any simple working example of the function in use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to create a new function as one already exists:

```
Math.max(num1, num2, num3);
```

Creating a new function is just extra overhead with no value added.

Answer (score 5):

```
function whatDidYouTry() {
    return Math.max.apply(null, arguments);
}
```

Comment: I thought that arguments were what went into the parenthesis after the function name?

Comment: @LDP: Those are formal parameters. Arguments are what was actually passed. You can reference arguments using formal parameters, or using the `arguments` object.

Answer (score 2):

```
function get_max(num1, num2, num3)
{
    var max = Math.max(num1, num2, num3);
    return max;
}

alert(get_max(20,3,5)); // 20
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/NmxQW/)
​

Comment: Why define your own function for this?  They can just use `Math.max(num1, num2, num3)` with no need for the `get_max()` function.

Comment: @jfriend00: Well the original question did state it had to be a function.

Comment: `Math.max` is such a function and it already exists.  It takes three arguments and returns the highest value.  It already exists.  There is no need to make a new superfluous function that wraps the one that already exists.  That adds no value.  I rather doubt the OP wants to create something that is not necessary and is not needed and is not any clearer.  If I asked you for a function that puts up an alert would you create a new function for that too?

Comment: Just answered the question as OP asked but I understand your logic. Thanks.

Comment: I believe that the best answers and the best citizens on SO give the OP the best overall advice which is NOT always a literal answer to their question when we know better.  Sometimes they don't ask for the right solution to their problem.

Comment: Got it but may be I'm not as good as you, still now learning but thanks again for your advise.

Comment: @jfriend00: You are definitely correct, thanks for educating me. Thou shalt be awarded the tick of power.

Comment: One more thing: you don't need to `alert` the function at the end. You can just call it with the assigned numbers, because the function is already set to return it's math.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a crack at it.

```
function threeNumberSort(a,b,c) {
    if (a<b) {
        if (a<c) {
            if (b<c) {
                console.log(a + ", then " + b + ", then " + c);
            } else {
                console.log (a + ", then " + c + ", then " + b);
            }
        } else {
            console.log (c + ", then " + a + ", then " + b);
        }
    } else {
        if (b<c) {
            if (a<c) {
               console.log (b + ", then " + a + ", then " + c); 
            } else {
                console.log (b + ", then " + c + ", then " + a);
            }
        } else {
            console.log (c + ", then " + b + ", then " + a);
        }
    }
}

threeNumberSort(1456,215,12488855);
```

This will print on your console:

```
215, then 1456, then 12488855
```

I have used the algorithm [I found on this page](http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs201/NOTES/chap03/sort.html). More efficient ones probably exist out there.

Answer (score 0):

This is the manual code I came up with using functions and else if statements:

```
function maxOfThree(a, b, c) {
    if ((a >= b) && (a >= c)) { 
        return a;
    } else if ((b >= a) && (b >= c)) {
        return b;
    } else {
        return c;
    }
}

console.log(maxOfThree(343,35124,42));
```